# How to create a range between date objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a blog still a noob in node.js and I created a homepage that should take recent posts for me to get the recent posts I want to use the date object saw on the Date object docs two methods I could try to filter the date on my models 
Date.getDate() this returns a number 
Date.now() current date also a number

My model query is written like this

let date = Date.getDate() - 1;

Post.find({postedOn: {$gt: Date.now, $lt: date}}).then().catch()

But I got an error that getDate is undefined any better ways I could do this and why was getDate undefined ?

Comment: you're using mongodb/mongoose?

Comment: Use new Date().getDate(); to get the date

Comment: yh it's mongoose I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
let date = new Date();

Post.find({
  postedOn: {
    $gt: date, 
    $lt: (date.setDate(date.getDate()-1))
  }
})
.then()
.catch()
```

You can use a specific date too, like:

```
Post.find({
 "postedOn": {
   "$gte": new Date(2019, 7, 22), 
   "$lt": new Date(2017, 7, 21)}
})
```